# How do I centre an svg path in an svg circle?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg of the GitHub logo (taken from [Simple Icons](https://simpleicons.org/icons/github.svg)).

I would like to centre this svg in a circle so it looks something like this:

[image]

I've tried taking the `path` from the svg and creating another svg with that `path` and a `circle`, like:

```css
svg {
  padding: 5px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

svg:hover {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg height="90" width="90">
  <circle cx="48%" cy="48%" r="48%" />
  <path d="M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12"/>
</svg>
```

But I don't know how to centre the `path` in the `circle`, how would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moment you start with `translate`
you will continue to stack `<g>` groups and `translates` like empty sushi plates at a party of 10

Instead, learn to edit [MDN: SVG paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

Tool of choice: **SVG Path Editor** https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

- Copy/paste d-path
- reduced presicion to 0 (for explanation purposes, but its always good to lower precision)

The path is:

```
M12 0c-7 0-12 5-12 12c0 5 3 10 8 11c1 0 1 0 1-1c0 0 0-1 0-2c-3 1-4-2-4-2C4 18 4 18 4 18
c-1-1 0-1 0-1c1 0 2 1 2 1c1 2 3 1 4 1c0-1 0-1 1-2c-3 0-6-1-6-6c0-1 1-2 1-3c0 0-1-2 0-3
c0 0 1 0 3 1c1 0 2 0 3 0c1 0 2 0 3 0c2-2 3-1 3-1c1 2 0 3 0 3c1 1 1 2 1 3c0 5-3 6-6 6
c0 0 1 1 1 2c0 2 0 3 0 3c0 0 0 1 1 1C21 22 24 18 24 12c0-7-5-12-12-12
```

- Learn SVG: M and m are **moves** C and c are **curves**
- capital M and C are **absolute** positioned points, we don't want those when we alter the path, because they would always stay at the **absolute** position
- **Convert to relative** in  the path editor

[image]

The path is:

```
m12 0c-7 0-12 5-12 12c0 5 3 10 8 11c1 0 1 0 1-1c0 0 0-1 0-2c-3 1-4-2-4-2c-1 0-1 0-1 0
c-1-1 0-1 0-1c1 0 2 1 2 1c1 2 3 1 4 1c0-1 0-1 1-2c-3 0-6-1-6-6c0-1 1-2 1-3c0 0-1-2 0-3
c0 0 1 0 3 1c1 0 2 0 3 0c1 0 2 0 3 0c2-2 3-1 3-1c1 2 0 3 0 3c1 1 1 2 1 3c0 5-3 6-6 6
c0 0 1 1 1 2c0 2 0 3 0 3c0 0 0 1 1 1c6-1 9-5 9-11c0-7-5-12-12-12
```

- That first `m12 0` **is** the **start DRAWING position**
- In the editor we see:

  - the top-left is 0,0
  - the (square) image is **24 units wide**
    (SVG is a vector format, they are not pixels)[image]
- to add space for a circle the image needs to be moved **6 units** right and **6 units** down
- That changes the `viewBox="0 0 24 24"` **to:** `viewBox="0 0 30 30"`

  - A `viewBox="0 0 W H"` is the most comfortable for your future SVG adventures.
  - A `viewBox="-15 -15 15 15"` is great when you do a lot of drawing **around** a (0,0) center point.
- Now instead of using `transform="translate(x y)"`,
  you **change the d-path start position** from `M12 0` **to:** `M15 3`

  - `new x  =  x + 6/2   =  12 + 3  = 15`
  - `new y  =  y + 6/2   =   0 + 3  =  3`
  - since it is the **first** path move, it doesn't matter if its `m15 3` or `M15 3`
  - use an extra `<rect>` to always see the viewBox size

```html
<svg height="90" width="90" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="pink"/>
  <circle r="48%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke="red" />
  <path d="M15 3c-7 0-12 5-12 12c0 5 3 10 8 11c1 0 1 0 1-1c0 0 0-1 0-2c-3 1-4-2-4-2c-1 0-1 0-1 0
c-1-1 0-1 0-1c1 0 2 1 2 1c1 2 3 1 4 1c0-1 0-1 1-2c-3 0-6-1-6-6c0-1 1-2 1-3c0 0-1-2 0-3
c0 0 1 0 3 1c1 0 2 0 3 0c1 0 2 0 3 0c2-2 3-1 3-1c1 2 0 3 0 3c1 1 1 2 1 3c0 5-3 6-6 6
c0 0 1 1 1 2c0 2 0 3 0 3c0 0 0 1 1 1c6-1 9-5 9-11c0-7-5-12-12-12"/>
</svg>
```

End result:

[image]

- One step (or giant leap) further is to write the `<circle>` as (part of) the **d-path**
  using: http://complexdan.com/svg-circleellipse-to-path-converter/

Comment: Perfect and thanks for the knowledge. Unfortunately the other answers with `translate` didn't work for me as it moved the `svg` relative to the other html elements.

Answer (score 2):

I used Illustrator to center the `path` and the `circle`

```css
svg {
  padding: 5px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 8;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

svg:hover {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="90" height="90" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <circle cx="258.96" cy="258.96" r="257.88"/>
  <path d="M258.96 81.73a181.74 181.74 0 00-57.47 354.15c9.09 1.71 12.42-3.91 12.42-8.74 0-4.32-.15-15.75-.23-30.89-50.55 11-61.21-24.38-61.21-24.38-8.27-21-20.22-26.58-20.22-26.58-16.46-11.27 1.27-11 1.27-11 18.25 1.27 27.84 18.72 27.84 18.72 16.2 27.79 42.54 19.76 52.93 15.11 1.64-11.75 6.32-19.76 11.51-24.31-40.36-4.54-82.78-20.17-82.78-89.81 0-19.84 7-36 18.7-48.76-2-4.59-8.18-23.06 1.59-48.1 0 0 15.22-4.88 50 18.63a171.34 171.34 0 0190.87 0c34.53-23.5 49.75-18.63 49.75-18.63 9.77 25 3.63 43.51 1.82 48.1 11.55 12.72 18.6 28.89 18.6 48.72 0 69.82-42.48 85.19-82.92 89.65 6.36 5.45 12.27 16.6 12.27 33.62 0 24.32-.23 43.86-.23 49.76 0 4.77 3.18 10.45 12.49 8.63a181.1 181.1 0 00124.73-172.16c0-100.36-81.37-181.73-181.73-181.73"/>
</svg>
```

**Edit:** An alternative way, numbers needed to be fine-tuned though, using a div instead of the circle:

```css
div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

svg path {
  transform: translate(11px, 10.5px) scale(2.8); 
}

.svg-container:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

.svg-container:hover svg {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg height="90" width="90">
  <path d="M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easier way would be drawing the circle and the path around the origin {x:0,y:0}. For this I've added a viewBox to the svg element whete the the first 2 paramaters (from x and from y) are negative. Now the center of the svg canvas is in the origin.

Next in order to center the circle around the origin I'm removing the cx and cy attributes (dhe default = 0)
In order to center the oath around the origin I'm calculating the bounding box and transtate the shape half width and half height to the left: `transform="translate(-12,-12)"`

```js
console.log(pth.getBBox())
```

```css
svg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

svg:hover {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg height="90" width="90" viewBox="-20 -20 40 40">
  <circle r="48%"  />
  
  <path id="pth" transform="translate(-12,-12)" d="M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Put your circle in group  and use transform="translate(x, y)".**

```
 <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
          <g transform="translate(200, 200)">
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="200" style="" fill="darkOrange"></circle>
          </g>
        </svg>
```