# Why is my SVG icon in the circle not visible?

Tags: html, css, svg

**The Markup**

```
<div class="pink-circle text-center">
        <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <mask id="maskCalendarHome" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="8" y="5" width="48" height="54">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M50.6667 10.6666H48V7.99998C48 6.53331 46.8 5.33331 45.3333 5.33331C43.8667 5.33331 42.6667 6.53331 42.6667 7.99998V10.6666H21.3333V7.99998C21.3333 6.53331 20.1333 5.33331 18.6667 5.33331C17.2 5.33331 16 6.53331 16 7.99998V10.6666H13.3333C10.3733 10.6666 8 13.0666 8 16V53.3333C8 56.2666 10.4 58.6666 13.3333 58.6666H50.6667C53.6 58.6666 56 56.2666 56 53.3333V16C56 13.0666 53.6 10.6666 50.6667 10.6666ZM32 18.6666C36.4267 18.6666 40 22.24 40 26.6666C40 31.0933 36.4267 34.6666 32 34.6666C27.5733 34.6666 24 31.0933 24 26.6666C24 22.24 27.5733 18.6666 32 18.6666ZM16 48.0006V50.6673H48V48.0006C48 42.6673 37.3333 39.734 32 39.734C26.6667 39.734 16 42.6673 16 48.0006Z" fill="black"/>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#maskCalendarHome)">
                <rect width="64" height="64" fill="#FF5F8F"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.pink-circle {
height:120px;
width:120px;
background: #FF5F8F;
opacity:0.1;
border-radius: 100%;}
```

**Expected Result**

[image]

**Current Result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svg is there, however you have used `opacity` in the parent which affects the children.

You may want to use a `background-color` with `rgba` values to add transparency to JUST the parent.

Like this:

```css
.pink-circle {
height:120px;
width:120px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
border-radius: 100%;
position:relative;
}
svg {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink-circle text-center">
        <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <mask id="maskCalendarHome" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="8" y="5" width="48" height="54">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M50.6667 10.6666H48V7.99998C48 6.53331 46.8 5.33331 45.3333 5.33331C43.8667 5.33331 42.6667 6.53331 42.6667 7.99998V10.6666H21.3333V7.99998C21.3333 6.53331 20.1333 5.33331 18.6667 5.33331C17.2 5.33331 16 6.53331 16 7.99998V10.6666H13.3333C10.3733 10.6666 8 13.0666 8 16V53.3333C8 56.2666 10.4 58.6666 13.3333 58.6666H50.6667C53.6 58.6666 56 56.2666 56 53.3333V16C56 13.0666 53.6 10.6666 50.6667 10.6666ZM32 18.6666C36.4267 18.6666 40 22.24 40 26.6666C40 31.0933 36.4267 34.6666 32 34.6666C27.5733 34.6666 24 31.0933 24 26.6666C24 22.24 27.5733 18.6666 32 18.6666ZM16 48.0006V50.6673H48V48.0006C48 42.6673 37.3333 39.734 32 39.734C26.6667 39.734 16 42.6673 16 48.0006Z" fill="black"/>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#maskCalendarHome)">
                <rect width="64" height="64" fill="#FF5F8F"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

**Edited:** I have added some `css` to center your `svg`

Comment: Thank you. Was a rookie mistake there by me. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

- fills and opacities and masks.. I can't even reason what's going on
- That icon was designed for a 80x80 viewBox
- Needs a cleanup
- You can do it all in SVG:

```html
<style>
  svg {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  svg:hover {
    opacity: 1
  }
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle fill="#FF5F8F" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%"/>
  <path   fill="red"     d="m59 18h-3v-3c0-1-1-3-3-3c-1 0-2 2-2 3v3h-22v-3c0-1-1-3-2-3
  c-2 0-3 2-3 3v3h-3c-3 0-5 2-5 5v37c0 3 2 6 5 6h38c3 0 5-3 5-6v-37c0-3-2-5-5-5zm-19 8
  c4 0 8 3 8 8c0 4-4 8-8 8c-4 0-8-4-8-8c0-5 4-8 8-8zm-16 29v3h32v-3c0-5-11-8-16-8
  c-5 0-16 3-16 8z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

**For long explanation:**

[How do I centre an svg path in an svg circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578103/how-do-i-centre-an-svg-path-in-an-svg-circle/66581674#66581674)